# Why Firebase 4.6.0 (ios) gave me "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"

Tags: ios, firebase, delphi, firebase-analytics

I update today firebase (ios) from **4.5.0** to **4.6.0**. With 4.5.0 it's was working well however with 4.6.0 (to the last 4.11.0) when I compile I have now this error :

> [DCC Error] E2597 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>       Error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:      objc-class-ref in
>   C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\firebase\FirebaseAnalytics.framework\FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAInAppPurchaseTransactionReporter_780d0e22c66d661ab61b3e74b77b38bd.o);
>
> Error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:      objc-class-ref in
>   C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\firebase\FirebaseAnalytics.framework\FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAProductsRequest_9354511b6e4f24cc2d512538458edb37.o);
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

I m using Delphi compiler (tokyo release 2) with ios 10.3 sdk.

this error only happen with the `FirebaseAnalytics.framework` (all other framework of 4.6.0 to 4.11.0 compile ok, only FirebaseAnalytics.framework make problems)

Any idea what was changed between 4.5.0 to 4.6.0 and what i can do to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not linking the *StoreKit* framework. Add *StoreKit.framework* to the configuration in Delphi that corresponds with Xcode's Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.

StoreKit has been a [FirebaseAnalytics dependency](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/4.1.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json#L11) for a long time, so I'm not sure why this is showing up now. I'm also not sure why you would update to Firebase 4.6.0 instead of the current latest 4.11.0.

Comment: You'll note that (from the tags) Loki is using Delphi, not Xcode. StoreKit is already included in the frameworks being linked in (though he has not mentioned that). For some reason or another, using Delphi 10.2.3 (Loki is using 10.2.2) linking against iOS 11.2 using Firebase 4.11.0 results in a successful compile. When I last checked (some time ago, probably with Delphi 10.2) linking against iOS 10.3 SDK did not

Comment: Where can we find "Build Phases" in Delphi IDE?

Comment: Upvoted because I'm using Xcode, but not CocoaPods, and this still solved my problem. Amazingly it's NOT documented in the "manual install" instructions in the README. You also need to link `libz` and `libsqlite3`, as I found in another S.O. answer...also not documented. Thanks!