# how to include external library in an iOs app?

Tags: ios, delphi

In `FirebaseCore.framework` i have this declaration :

```
@interface FIRApp : NSObject

+ (void)configure;

@end
```

I declare in delphi an object like this :

```
  FIRAppClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
  ['{37BEFC11-8AE6-4312-971D-53BF9D8DB22A}']
    procedure configure; cdecl;
  end;
  FIRApp = interface(NSObject)
  ['{69F89279-48F0-4276-B337-37FE79821507}']
  end;
  TFIRApp = class(TOCGenericImport<FIRAppClass, FIRApp>) end;
```

Now when i run `TFIRApp.OCClass.configure` i receive an error "**ObjectiveC class FIRApp could not be found**"

What I miss ? how to include in my iOS app the FirebaseCore.framework and implement the FIRApp ?

Answer (score 4):

> "ObjectiveC class FIRApp could not be found"

That error means `FIRApp` class was not fully linked to your application. In order to do that you need to add `-ObjC` flag to Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking -> Options passed to LD linker

[image]

Comment: thanks Dalija, however when i add -Objc i have now another error but this time at compile time: [DCC Error] E2597 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: Error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from: objc-class-ref in C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\firebase\FirebaseAnalytics.framework\FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAInAppPurchaseTransactionReporter_780d0e22c66d661ab61b3e74b77b38bd.o); ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712340/why-firebase-4-6-0-ios-gave-me-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7 )

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with that part... if you have StoreKit included it should work, but it does not... I know, I have similar issues... Have you tried with 10.2.3 update? I am not saying it will work... because it most likely will not, but you never know...

Comment: thanks dalija, no didn't try the 10.2.3 only the 10.2.2 because it's complicate to migrate, but i don't think something change in the 10.2.3 or i m mistaken ?

Comment: One nasty crashing bug was resolved for Android connected with OpenGL context finalization.

Comment: hmmm you mean about the bug that raise an exception when we close the app?

Comment: Yes. I think 10.2.3 is worth upgrading for that one alone. there are other thing fixed, but I wasn't paying close attention. Also it doesn't seem they broke anything. At least not anything substantial :) Of course, this does not mean your current issue will be resolved with upgrade. I have similar issues as yours with Firebase and 10.2.3.

Comment: ahah i correct myself this bug from the day i install the release 2 ;) also it's not really important bug because it's appear only when we close the app and we don't really care except in debugger about any exception at the closing time (on iOS for exemple the closing will be even never called) ..

Comment: On the android device I have this bug caused visible crash.

Comment: woow that something i was not aware ! i will do more intensive test so...

Comment: but anyway upgrading is very very painfull, uninstall old version to reinstall new one on the top, source of delphi change and you must redebug everything and if something go wrong you are in the ##{~ because need to uninstall reinstall old one ... very painfull process ! worse they can do